# Need Serialize a custom filed AVG notes for my API in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, aggregate-functions, django-serializer

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Avg
from users.models import UserProfile
from subjects.models import Subject


class Note(models.Model):
    id_user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_note')
    id_subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subject_note')
    exam_note = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def average_note(self):
        if hasattr(self, '_average_note'):
            return self._average_note
        return Note.objects.aggregate(Avg('exam_note'))
```

***Thats my Note models and i need to calculate the notes average to serialize it and send in request resonse***

## views.py

```
class AvgNoteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AvgSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (NotePermissions,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Note.objects.all().annotate(_average_note=Avg('exam_note'))
```

***And that is my get_queryset redefined method to calculate de average notes, but im just having a list of notes for result of that query, like that:*** [resques response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ixoX.png)

## serializers.py

```
class AvgSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializes a notes AVG
    """

    average_note = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_average_note(self, obj):
        return obj.average_note

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ['average_note']
```

***And this is my serializer***

**My intencion is try to get an avergate from the exam_notes from the logged user, so i understand that i need to try to group by user_id ant then agregate the average. This is my postgresql table from when im querying: [notes_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5oit.png)**

I based my code from [How to calculate average of some field in Django models and send it to rest API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68953258/how-to-calculate-average-of-some-field-in-django-models-and-send-it-to-rest-api), but im trying to get some result like as running the following query:

```
SELECT avg(exam_note) 
FROM public.notes_note x
group by id_user_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a GROUP BY functionality, you’ll simply add `values` to your get_queryset method like this:

```py
class AvgNoteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AvgSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (NotePermissions,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Note.objects.all().values('id_user').annotate(_average_note=Avg('exam_note'))
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helps me, and i needed to change a little bit my serializer like that:
 @staticmethod
    def get_average_note(obj):
        return obj['_average_note']